# CSS property "background-image" work for body and not for class

Tags: html, css

As in the title, the problem is that background-image works only if I use it with body, but it doesn't work if I use it for example to the .main class. Why?

An example of what **doesn't** work:

```css
.main{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwaJj.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">

  </div>
</body>
```

**This working properly.**

```css
body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwaJj.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.main{
    margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
    font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
    padding: 0px 10px;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your element has not height, you need to define a height or add some content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of the height property is `auto` for all elements. Since there is no element present in the div element so the height of the div element is 0 in your case, so the image is not fit in the div element.

You can set the height of the div element to auto or any pixel value(if the value exceeds it will overflow ).

`height: auto;` or `height: 20px:`

@Edited:

> According to the [official docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#root-background), The background of the root element becomes the canvas background and its background painting area extends to cover the entire canvas.

The HTML element is the root element. Now, according to your case, you have set the background image to body element and not in HTML element. Thanks to [background propagation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#body-background) it will check the background for the root element first and if it is not there then it will propagate to `body` element background. As you have set the background image to body so the background image will apply to whole canvas.

Tip: Canvas size is infinite but user agent set its size to the target device.

Comment: Set `height:100%;` to your div element to fit the background image.

Answer (score 3):

I think it will work for class. But your div has not anything. Just try add:

```
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
```

into your class.

Answer (score 3):

By default, your Html and body elements are only as high as the actual page content and the `div` element has a `height` of `0` so even if the background is applied the `height` is `0` and cannot show. Simple add height to your `main` CSS like so.

```
    .main{
        margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
        font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
        padding: 0px 10px;
        height: 400px;
    }
```

Comment: *By default, the body element takes up the height of the actual page* this is not true, inspect the element and you will see the body having a height:0

Comment: The `html` element takes the full height of the document, not the `body` element.